# Select the row with the maximum value and its information in R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame *DF* with sites, an ID number and a diversity index. I want to select the site and ID with the maximum index number (site 6 in this example). It basically looks like this.

```
Sites                 ID  Shannon.index
Site 1                1   1.9555920
Site 2                2   1.5091915
Site 3                3   1.9630550
Site 4                4   1.1068400
Site 5                5   1.8947205
Site 6                6   3.1657865 #Max. index number
Site 7                7   2.0000802
```

However, when I try selecting the information with `DF[max(DF$Shannon.index), ]`, I receive the following:

```
Sites    ID   Shannon.index
Site 3    3   1.9630550
```

Basically, R is selecting the information from the 3rd row, and not the row with my maximum number of 3.16. How can I tell R that I want the column information for the maximum index number, and not the information from the row position in which the maximum number starts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `which.max` that returns the index

```
DF[which.max(DF$Shannon.index),]
```

---

When we take the `max`, it returns the value `3.1657865` and it is floored to return the 3rd row